# form wont move in css no matter what i try

Tags: html, css, forms

Hi everybody i bin working on a lil website but my form won't move no matter what i do it just seem to be stuck i tried floating position margin but it doesnt work and i cant find the solution

my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>



<!--Title-->
<div id="Title">
     <h1>Magic</h1>
</div>






<!--Navigator-->
<div id="Nav">
  <form action="skyrim.html">
     <input type="submit" value="Map">
     </form>
   
  <form action="races.html">
  <input type="submit" value="Races">
  </form>
   
  <form action="magic.html">
  <input type="submit" value="Magic">
  </form>
   
  <form action="Website 1.html">
  <input type="submit" value="Homepage">
  </form>
</div>





<!--Section-->
<div id="Sector">
     <h1> Skyrim Magic Categories</h1>
</div>




<!--Magic-->
<div id="Dmagic">
     <img src="Dmagic.png" alt="Dmagic.png" style="width:350px;length:300px;">
</div>




  
  
<!--Login Form-->
<div id="Form">
  <form action="logged.html">
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Dovahkiin">
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="Dragonborn">
  <input type="submit" name="Log in" value="Log in">
  </form>
</div>
    
   


   
<!--footer-->
<div id="Footer">
     <p>Made by Tommasteragent</p>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

my css code

```css
<style>
div#Form  {
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:-150px;
  }
div#Title {
        font-size:30px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:black;
  padding:5px;
  }
  
div#Nav    {
         font-size:20px;
   color:black;
   float:left;
   background-color:lightgrey;
   padding:5px;
   line-height:50px;
   height:770px;
   width:100px;
   }
   
div#Footer  {
         font-size:20px;
   color:white;
   background-color:black;
   padding:5px;
   clear:both;
   text-align:center;
   }

div#Sector   {
         background-color:white;
   color:black;
   float:left;
   clear:right;
   width:350;
   padding:10px;
   }
div#Dmagic  {
          position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:70px;
   }
</style>
```

already thank you for you help

EDIT
Yeah sorry about being unclear about my problem
The question mainly goes about the "Login Form" "div#Form"
Thats the part that won't move it needs to be in the top right corner but it wont

My excuses for being unclear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using forms? if you use a `<a href="skyrim.html"> skyrim</a>` it will be a lot easer to style

Answer (score 0):

I gather you're trying to move it sideways. Then the attribute you're looking for is "margin". This adds the given amount of pixels to either side of the element. Setting "margin" to "auto" will center it.

// edit:

Don't use forms for navigation. User links (`<a>` -element) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to move the form to below the text 'skyrim magic categories'. I have made some edit in your css please update this and your form will move.

```
div#Sector   {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    clear:right;
    width:350;
    padding:10px;
}
div#Dmagic  {
    top:200px;
    left:70px;
}
```

I have removed float from sector and position from dmagic element.

(In case you don't want to remove float then add width to sector element and make it block. )

Comment: I added the code but the login form still wont move to the top right